# i need to validate my car registration number as following 131-D-12345 format in php?

Tags: php, html

i've tried the following but its not working ? So what pattern do i use to validate the format 131-D-12345

php code below:

```
 $RegistrationNumber = trim($_POST['RegistrationNumber']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z]{1}-[0-9]{5}*$/",$RegistrationNumber)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid RegistrationNumber! use only following format 131-D-12345";
```

html code below

```
<label for="RegistrationNumber" class="form-label">Registration Number (use Dublin registration) </label>
          <input type="text" name="RegistrationNumber" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  maxlength=20 >
```

Comment: Remove the `*`. [example](https://regex101.com/r/zZ5R4m/1) without that present.

Comment: i removed the * and still not working?

Comment: Try escaping the in-between hyphens: `\-`. What is your PHP version?

Comment: Please give examples to reproduce. "Not working" is no error description.

Comment: @PaulT. `-` outside `[]` does not need escaping, if needed inside `[]` make it the first character: `[-a-z]`

Comment: use an online regex tool and gradually add to the regex and see which part is the problem

Comment: @rioV8 ... understood on that, worked both ways at the example link. Not sure why it `didn't work` with the `*` removed.

Comment: hi, so  its working with the * removed "/^[0-9]{3}-[D]{1}-[0-9]{5}$/"